# Get all HTML content from DOMParser, excluding the outer body tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dynamic, html-parsing

I'm using `DOMParser` in the following code.

```js
let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<b>sample text</b> <i>sample text</i>', 'text/html');
document.querySelector('.js').append(doc.body);
```

```html
<span><b>sample text</b> <i>sample text</i></span>
<span><b>sample text</b> <i>sample text</i></span>
<span class='js'></span>
```

When I run it, it gives the HTML content properly, but the issue is that the **outer `body` tag** is also included in the result, which makes the content to have **`block` display**. Actually, I need to preserve the `inline` display, as seen in previous two `span`s.

I thought it's because of `doc.body` statement, so I tried to change it to `doc.body.firstChild` (which returns only `b` element) and `doc.body.children` (which returns `[Object HTMLCollection]`), but none of them worked.

How to fix it?

---

**Note:** `<span><b>sample text</b> <i>sample text</i></span>` is a dynamic content on my webpage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing

```
document.querySelector('.js').append(...doc.body.children);
```

```js
let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<b>sample text</b> <i>sample text</i>', 'text/html');
document.querySelector('.js').append(...doc.body.children);
```

```html
<span><b>sample text</b> <i>sample text</i></span>
<span><b>sample text</b> <i>sample text</i></span>
<span class='js'></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope that my understanding is right! You are trying to display the content similar to the previous span tags. Assigning string value to the innerHTML content could help, in which case there is no need to use the DOMParser. Probably use innerHTML way to preserve inline style.

```
const htmlContent = '<b>sample text</b>'
document.querySelector('.js').innerHTML = htmlContent;
```

If there is still a requirement to use DOMParser, then you could probably do

```
document.querySelector('.js').innerHTML = doc.body.innerHTML
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: setting innerHTML directly removes all previous children the parent element might have had and appending to innerHTML would remove all javascript references to all previous children that might exist.
So only use this if the container doesn´t have children or if they should be replaced.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm using `.append` method in order to add multiple elements in succession, so I can't do `innerHTML`. Anyways, thank you.